# Getting JsonException while using JSONML.toJSONObject()

Tags: java, json, jsonml

I'm using JSONML for converting xml String to JSONObject. 
This is my xml String

```
"<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><jsonArray><jsonElement><message>entity is deleted<\/message><errorCode>ENTITY_IS_DELETED<\/errorCode><\/jsonElement><jsonElement><message>entity is deleted<\/message><errorCode>ENTITY_IS_DELETED<\/errorCode><\/jsonElement><\/jsonArray><\/soapenv:Body>"
```

when I try `JSONML.toJSONObject()` It gives me

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Bad character in a name at 32 [character 33 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.XMLTokener.nextToken(XMLTokener.java:288)
    at org.json.JSONML.parse(JSONML.java:173)
    at org.json.JSONML.toJSONObject(JSONML.java:286)
    at org.json.JSONML.toJSONObject(JSONML.java:304)
    at com.thbs.automaton.commonUtils.TestcaseUtils.compareXml(TestcaseUtils.java:144)
    ... 57 more
```

Its due to the escape character (\). I tried resolving this by removing all the \ characters , which solved my problem. However I don't think its a good practice.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: How did you get the String? You seem to be using a tool that makes a useless conversion to a non XML String.

Answer (score 1):

The "\"s shows the original String is not a "XML String". It is an "escaped XML String". You should find out why and how the XML String is escaped.

Maybe it because of transferring as JSON. In that case, you should transform the original(JSON) String into data String, so to say a XML String. With code like this

```
String xmlString = jsonParser(originalString, String.class);
```

after that run as yours

```
JSONML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
```

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: which class is this jsonParser?

Comment: There are lots of JSON libraries. Like GSON, jackson, fastjson, etc. But please make sure it's a json string, first. Maybe the provider of the string will provide this information, too. Meanwhile, you can use the same library as the provider, if you are using the same programming language.